# Teamcity - create dependency builds, whose svn repos are different from each other

Tags: svn, dependencies, teamcity

I am trying to set up a dummy build configuration which does nothing apart from building other projects (build configurations) in Teamcity. I have 4 build configurations which are getting built perfectly fine without any issues. All these 4 build configurations are actually from 3 different SVN repositories

looks like the below structure.

1. build configuraiton A - http://svn.example.com/repo1/folderA
2. build configuraiton B - http://svn.example.com/repo2/folderB/folderxyxz
3. build configuraiton C - http://svn.example.com/repo1/folderC
4. build configuraiton D - http://svn.example.com/repo3/folderD/folderabcd

I would like to create a dummy build configuration and make sure that, when I run this dummy build, it should build all the builds from A to D. How can i achieve this ? I know about snapshot dependency, but I heard that all the build configurations should be from same svn repo. I might be wrong, please correct me..

For your information, I am using TeamCity Professional 8.1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Snapshot dependencies](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Snapshot+Dependencies) can be configured for build configurations with different VCS roots. Uncheck option "Do not run new build if there is a suitable one" if you want always to rerun the whole build chain. For more details read about [Dependencies Setup](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Build+Dependencies+Setup#BuildDependenciesSetup-SnapshotDependencies).

Comment: Thank you Alina Mishina, I read about this just few hours back and set up my builds accordingly. However, how can I re-order them in teamcity, by default snapshot dependencies are all getting executed in the alphabetical order...  I am looking for my builds to be executed in a particular order but teamcity is building them in alphabetical order... my set up is done except re-ordering these builds. Once again many thanks to both of you !!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add Build trigger  on "Finish build" condition. What that means is you can say that Build B will be trigerred when Build A completes.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. But in this case, if I select build trigger "Finish build" Build B will always be triggered whenever Build A completes... Sometimes, I just need to work on only Build A but not on Build B... I think build dependency is good option for my particular need as I asked in the question ....I am still figuring it out the solution.